# Braintree Google Pay sandbox opens live domain

Tags: paypal, sandbox, braintree, google-pay

I'm trying to integrate Google Pay at my page, as expected doing that first at Sandbox environment but I face a problem that when I click the Google Pay button it opens the live domain and asks me to enter a real card, although I setup up all related to Sandbox environment.

Here is the code following [BT documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/google-pay/client-side/javascript/v3).

```
  var createGooglePaymentComponent = function(clientInstance){
    var button = document.querySelector('#google-pay-button');
    var paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
      environment: 'TEST' // Or 'PRODUCTION'
    });

    braintree.googlePayment.create({
      client: clientInstance,
      googlePayVersion: 2,
    }, function (googlePaymentErr, googlePaymentInstance) {
      paymentsClient.isReadyToPay({
        apiVersion: 2,
        apiVersionMinor: 0,
        allowedPaymentMethods: googlePaymentInstance.createPaymentDataRequest().allowedPaymentMethods,
      }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.result) {
          button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var paymentDataRequest = googlePaymentInstance.createPaymentDataRequest({
              transactionInfo: {
                currencyCode: 'USD',
                totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
                totalPrice: '100.00',
              }
            });
            var cardPaymentMethod = paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods[0];
            cardPaymentMethod.parameters.billingAddressRequired = true;

            paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest).then(function(paymentData) {
              googlePaymentInstance.parseResponse(paymentData, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  // Handle parsing error
                }
                // Send result.nonce to your server
              });
            }).catch(function (err) {
            });
          });
        }
      }).catch(function (err) {
      });
    });
  };
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get:

[image: Google Pay button overlay]

Any idea why does that happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Google Pay in the TEST environment will return a TEST payment credential which won't actually charge the payment method that you provide. It's understandable that you don't want to be using *real* payment details.

If you want to be able to choose from a list of predefined test cards, follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/test-card-suite

In short, you will need to join the [googlepay-test-mode-stub-data Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data) which will then display a list of test accounts when accessing the Google Pay payment sheet with that user.